# edit meta comment tag of an mkv file

Tags: shell, video, encoding, command-line, mkv

I use mkvpropedit to edit the meta tag title of some mkv files which works great.

```
find . -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'mkvpropedit --set "title=$(basename "$1")" "$1"' sh '{}' \;
```

but I also want to edit the comment tag, but whatever I try I always get:

```
Error: The name 'comment' is not a valid property name for the current edit specification in '--set comment= '
```

the man page of mkvpropedit explains only that --set is followerd by name=value and that's also everything I could find online, no decription of what the possible names are

Comment: The TagName SHOULD always be written in all capital letters. Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been like 2 years but, I recently had this error and was able to find its solution.

The thing is this command is specifically to edit properties, but not tags, as comments are tags, you need to use an XML file to add the comment attribute.

First, you need to set up the XML file with the following information:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE Tags SYSTEM "matroskatags.dtd"> -->
<Tags>
  <Tag>
    <Targets />
    <Simple>
      <Name>COMMENT</Name>
      <String>Comment you wish to add</String>
    </Simple>
  </Tag>
</Tags>
```

Next you need to run the following command

```
mkvpropedit filename.mkv --tags all:comment.xml
```

I recommend using mkvextract to extract the existing tags and adding the ones you wish to add, otherwise a lot of them might be deleted.

```
mkvextract my_movie.mkv tags tag_file.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Running `mkvpropedit -l` will show you a list of all the properties you can edit using mkvpropedit. If you need to add custom tags which are not in this list then you should look at ExifTool

Comment: ExifTool doesn't seem to support MKV